# Kibana no default index pattern

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I use ELK and I've just sent DELETE /* request to http://localhost:9002. Then I refreshed Kibana page but I got this error

```
Index Patterns 
Warning No default index pattern. You must select or create one to continue.

In order to use Kibana you must configure at least one index pattern. Index patterns are used to identify the Elasticsearch index to run search and analytics against. They are also used to configure fields.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, might be stating the obvious here, but are you shipping any data? This message is usually displayed when there the pipeline is not functioning correctly - i.e. logs not being forwarded from Logstash to Elasticsearch.